# Chop a string, change variables values ​and return to the same function

Tags: javascript

I have always given them my try codes, but this time there is something I cannot accomplish.

I need to learn, I don't want a solution without explanation, the idea is that the next time I am faced with something similar I will do it alone.

**PROBLEM:**

I have noticed that *for some songs* a lyrics API does not find the lyric, but if I make a change it does find it.

**Examples that the lyric CANNOT find (for some songs):**
`currentArtist =` 'Robin Schulz feat. Erika Sirola'
**or**
'Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola'
**or**
'Robin Schulz (feat. Erika Sirola)'
**or**
'Robin Schulz (Feat. Erika Sirola)'
`currentSong =` 'Speechless'

**But if it finds** the lyric if I look for it like this:
`currentArtist =` 'Robin Schulz'
`currentSong =` 'Speechless (Feat. Erika Sirola)'

When the API does not find the lyric the 1st time, my idea is to compare if `currentArtist` contains or not the words Feat. or feat. with or without parentheses, to remove it and add that chunk to `currentSong`. Then make the changes to currentArtist and currentSong so that it tries one more time with the new values.

As I mentioned at the beginning, *some lyrics* are found with the Feat./feat. inside currentArtist, that's why I have to make the changes in the `ELSE` that I have indicated in the code and not before.

**In conclusion:**
If the API does not find the artist containing Feat. X, feat. x, (Feat. x) or (feat. x) remove that part of the artist name and add it to the song name.
`currentSong` always has to go like this: Song Name (Feat. x) even if the artist name does not have parentheses in the Feat. It should then return to the same function with the new values ​​for `currentArtist` and `currentSong`.

```
// DOM control
function Page() {
    this.changeTitlePage = function (title = RADIO_NAME) {
        document.title = title;
    };
    
    this.refreshLyric = function(currentSong, currentArtist) {
                      
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status === 200) {
             var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    if (data.type === 'exact' || data.type === 'aprox') {
                        //lyric found
                        var lyric = normalizeText(data, currentArtist);
                                            
                        document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                        
                    } else {
                        //lyric NOT found
                        //HERE before going to page.refreshLyric2 change values currentSong & currentArtist ​​and return to this.refreshLyric
                        //If after the changes it still cannot find the lyric go to page.refreshLyric2
                        //......
                        //......
                        //......
                        var page = new Page();
                        page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                    }
                } else {
                    //Error
                   var page = new Page();
                    page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                   }
            }
        }
            xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + vagalume_api + '&apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + currentArtist + '&mus=' + currentSong.toLowerCase()), true);
            xhttp.send()
    }
}
```

In the end I share the **complete solution**, if someone can improve it by reducing the code, that would be great. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```js
// Set currentArtist & currentSong
 let Artist = 'Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola';
 let Song = 'Speechless';
                       
 // convert sting Artist to array
let arrayArtist = Artist.split(" ");
                        
                            
//find items containing *Feat*
if (findIndex(arrayArtist) !== -1) {
let lengthArtist = arrayArtist.length;
let i = findIndex(arrayArtist);
                                                
//remove Feat. and all the following words
artistSplited = arrayArtist.slice(0,i);
                        
//final result of Artist without (Feat. x)
Artist = artistSplited.join(' ');
                        
//get text removed from artist name Feat. xxx
let featSongSplited = arrayArtist.slice(i, lengthArtist);
//join previous text in featSongJoined
let featSongpreJoined = featSongSplited.join(' ');
let featSongJoined = featSongpreJoined.replace(/[()]/g, '');
                        
//final result of Song with (Feat. x)
Song = Song + ' (' + featSongJoined + ')';
                                                   
    console.log ("New Artist Name:", Artist);
    console.log("New Song Name:", Song)
    }
     
function findIndex(text){
  const words = ["feat.","Feat.","(feat.)","(Feat.)"];
  
  for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    const index = text.indexOf(words[i]);
    if(index !== -1) return index;
  }
  
  return -1;
}
```

**SOLUTION IMPLEMENTED IN THE FUNCTION:**

```
 // DOM control
function Page() {
    this.changeTitlePage = function (title = RADIO_NAME) {
    document.title = title;
    };
            
        this.refreshLyric = function(currentSong, currentArtist) {
                              
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                  if (this.status === 200) {
                     var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
                            if (data.type === 'exact' || data.type === 'aprox') {
                                //lyric found
                                var lyric = normalizeText(data, currentArtist);
                                                    
                                document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                                
                            } else {
                                // Set currentArtist & currentSong
                                let Artist = currentArtist;
                                let Song = currentSong;
                                                       
                                // convert sting Artist to array
                                let arrayArtist = Artist.split(" ");
                                                        
                                                            
                                //find items containing *Feat*
                                if (findIndex(arrayArtist) !== -1) {
                                let lengthArtist = arrayArtist.length;
                                let i = findIndex(arrayArtist);
                                                                                
                                //remove Feat. and all the following words
                                artistSplited = arrayArtist.slice(0,i);
                                                        
                                //final result of Artist without (Feat. x)
                                Artist = artistSplited.join(' ');
                                                        
                                //get text removed from artist name Feat. xxx
                                let featSongSplited = arrayArtist.slice(i, lengthArtist);
                                //join previous text in featSongJoined
                                let featSongpreJoined = featSongSplited.join(' ');
                                let featSongJoined = featSongpreJoined.replace(/[()]/g, '');
                                                        
                                //final result of Song with (Feat. x)
                                Song = Song + ' (' + featSongJoined + ')';
                                
                                //return the new values ​​to the function
                                var page = new Page();
                                page.refreshLyric(Song, Artist);
                        
                                } else {
                                var page = new Page();
                                page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                   var page = new Page();
                    page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                   }
                }
            }
            xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + vagalume_api + '&apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + urlencode(currentArtist) + '&mus=' + urlencode(currentSong.toLowerCase()), true);
            xhttp.send()
        }
}
     
function findIndex(text){
  const words = ["feat.","Feat.","(feat.)","(Feat.)"];
  
  for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    const index = text.indexOf(words[i]);
    if(index !== -1) return index;
  }
  
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a regex match.

First remove the parenthesis with `.replace(/\)|\(/gm, '')`. This assumes that artists don't use parenthesis in their names.

Then extract with:

```js
/* First match is the name, second match is the featured */
new RegExp(/(.*) feat\.? (.*)/igm)
```

Comment: my English is not good, maybe I did not express myself well. Now I have shared a partial solution so you can really see what I want.